# Working with some of UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview

How to select several `UITableViewCell` (as a checkmark but with my own style) and then do something with selected items?

As a checkmark (or something else) I would like to use `UIImageView`:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To add to [Pandu1251's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15245279/46297), if you want to use your own check mark image, you can set a custom accessory view and follow the same logic that he has specified.

To set a custom accessory view, use

```
cell.accessoryView = myAccessoryView; //myAccessoryView is a UIImageView holding your custom check mark image
```

Comment: I think it is what I need... How to link my UIImageView with cell.accessoryView?

Comment: Create a UIImageView object with your image and then set the accessoryView to your imageview (i.e. replace the myAccessoryView with your imageview's variable name)

Answer (score 0):

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *) tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *) indexPath

{

```
UITableViewCell *thisCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
if (thisCell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone)
{
    thisCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;

}
else
{
  for(int i=0;i<[Array count];i++)
  {
    thisCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
  }

  thisCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}
```

}

Now try this......

Comment: ...I would like to check not only one cell, but several (like on the screen above)

Comment: now it works fine! Thanks! can I put my UIImageView instead of check sign (like on screen - crosses line)?

Answer (score 0):

Just do as follow. For that you have to take NSMutableArray. i have taken arrMethodsToBeStored here.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];

    cell.textLabel.textColor=[UIColor darkGrayColor];
    cell.textLabel.font= [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial Rounded MT Bold" size:15.0];

    Scope_RepairMethod *scpObj=[repairMethodArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text= scpObj.strRepairMethod;

    if([self.checkedIndexPath isEqual:indexPath])
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }
    else
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   // NSString *selID;

    UITableViewCell *newCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    Scope_RepairMethod *scpObj=[repairMethodArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    if (newCell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone)
    {
        newCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        [arrMethodsToBeStored addObject:scpObj.strRepairMethod];
    }
    else
    {
        newCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        [arrMethodsToBeStored removeObject:scpObj.strRepairMethod];
    }
    NSLog(@"selected method arr==== %@",arrMethodsToBeStored);


// I want to enable my save button only if one or more values from table are selected

    if(arrMethodsToBeStored.count > 0)
        saveBtn.enabled=true;
    else
    {
        saveBtn.enabled=false;
    }
}
```